# To add arguments or to add an array?

Tags: javascript

I have this chunk of code [sourced from different user on this site—thanks!] that I need to modify so that I can check multiple fields instead of just one. I'm not sure if I should be adding arguments to the second function or turn the variable checkString to an array.

```
function getField(fieldType, fieldTitle) {
    var docTags = document.getElementsByTagName(fieldType);
    for (var i = 0; i < docTags.length; i++) {
        if (docTags[i].title == fieldTitle) {
            return docTags[i]
        }
    }
}

function checkField() {
    var checkString = getField('input', 'fieldtocheck').value;
    if (checkString != "") {
        if (/[^A-Za-z\d]/.test(checkString)) {
            alert("Please enter only alphanumeric characters for the field fieldtocheck");
            return (false);
        }
    }
}
```

I think the best option would be to feed "getfield" into the the "checkfield" as arguments but how would I do that?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean you want to turn it into an array? An array of what?

Comment: I could have my wording wrong but I mean to turn the variable "checkString" so that is contains multiple values. I think thats an array yes?

Answer (score 2):

I would make your function more generic and use a class to identify the fields:

```
function checkFields(className, regex) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (!regex.match(inputs[i].value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function validate() {
    if (!checkFields('alphanum', /^[A-Za-z\d]+$/)) {
        alert('Please enter only alphanumeric characters');
    }
}
```

And your HTML could look like this:

```
<input type="text" class="alphanum" />
```

A much simpler (and better, IMO) approach would be to use the [jQuery validation plugin](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation).

Comment: Hi Blender, thanks for this. This code is to go on a sharepoint site so adding classes to a field can be [with my experience] complicated. Especially form list form fields which is why we're using the fieldTitle function. Regardless I kinda see where your going so I'll have a play and see what I can come up with.